# getting error while starting apache (version is 2.4.33)

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I am getting below error while starting apache.

httpd: Syntax error on line 153 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: undefined symbol: ap_accept_lock_mech

mod_wsgi is 4.6.4 
apache version is 2.4.33

did anyone else face this issue ?

Comment: Make sure the ``-dev`` package for Apache matches the runtime package version. This message suggests mod_wsgi was compiled against header files from a version of Apache very different to what is being used at runtime. How exactly did you build mod_wsgi? If used the ``pip install`` method, make sure you don't have ``mod_wsgi-httpd`` Python package installed when compiling mod_wsgi.

Comment: i installed like below 

yum install httpd-devel -y
    wget https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.6.4.tar.gz
    tar -xzvf 4.6.4.tar.gz
    cd mod_wsgi-4.6.4
    ./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7  LDFLAGS="-R/usr/local/lib"
 make
 make install

Comment: Make sure your httpd package is up to date with the devel package then.